# Solution for word-wrapping and breaking my grid

Tags: css, youtube, word-wrap

Im trying to make a setup that is similar to youtubes grid of videos.

The problem comes with the titles. I see youtube shortens the titles with '...' and are no longer then two lines long.

Im not sure how to do this so im working with what i have available.

Here is an image of what the video grid looks like with a placeholder title and it looks and works fine:

[image]

---

Then when i apply the actual titles to the video grid, they are too long and break the grid.
[image]

---

Then i try different CSS to try to collapse or break the words appart such as: `word-wrap` and `white-space`. None of the available parameters work for some reason. So i try to apply a `width` to it, in an effort to "squeeze" the words together. That kinda works but it breaks the grid veritcally.

[image]

Is there a another way i should go about this? 
Here is the website so you can try to play with it if you want: [iCODFilms](http://callofdutyfilms.com/daily-clips/)

Comment: technical/accessibility reasons preventing you from using tables?

Comment: tables actually could work out well here. Im just so used to table-less design. i will consider it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set also a min-height making all of them reserve the space (gap) for 2 lines or...
[jQuery equalheights plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/)

Comment: equalheights plugin here would create unnecessary padding below all the blocks even if they are on a different row.

Comment: $(function() {
 $('.codfilms-video-list').equalHeights(true);
 
}); that seems right and i combined the script file with my own file too.

Comment: Try putting it inside 

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});

Answer (score 1):

if u r willing to use JS for solution, then use jquery masonry. It is the right way to solve this issue. http://masonry.desandro.com/

You will need to fix the width of each of the blocks and then use the plugin.

@Haso Keric suggested to use equalheights plugin, but it would leave unnecessary gap below all your blocks.

Comment: this would work great for a picture grid but it doesn't look good for video grid. thanks

Answer (score 0):

give your title container a specific width this way your title will wrap around it.

for better help, show the html structure for a single video container, and also provide the css you are using. This way we can give you a more specific solution

Comment: i included the webpage at the bottom